# HTML Page not rendered on changing url-pattern for Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Home.java file

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-
    INF/views/Login.html");
view.include(request, response);
```

web.xml file

This works --

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>home.Home</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

This doesn't work --

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>home.Home</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

In the second case there is repititive error printing in the console.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Home] threw exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:409)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:409)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:409)
```

I have found questions on stackoverflow about the same error but I cant understand any of them

[java.lang.StackOverflowError being thrown by class that doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221269/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-being-thrown-by-class-that-doesnt-exist)

[Faces Servlet threw exception java.lang.StackOverflowError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85532/faces-servlet-threw-exception-java-lang-stackoverflowerror)

Comment: `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` means: **all** requests, to **any** path, are handled by this servlet. So you're forwarding to the same servlet, which is forwarding to the same servlet, etc. etc., hence the StackOverflowError

Comment: So what should I do to render an HTML page when the user lands at '/' the root.

Comment: Google is your friend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030302/how-can-i-map-a-root-servlet-so-that-other-scripts-are-still-runnable

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet . The problem is resolved.